# How to get logical types from schema registry to avro files using Kafka GSC Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm loading avro files into GCS using Kafka GCS connector. In my schema in the schema registry I have logical types on some of my columns, but it seems like they're not being transferred to the files. How can logical types from a schema be transferred to avro files?
Here is my connector configuration for what it's worth:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector",
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka.internal:9092",
  "flush.size": "200000",
  "tasks.max": "300",
  "topics": "prod_ny, prod_vr",
  "group.id": "gcs_sink_connect",
  "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy",
  "gcs.credentials.json": "---",
  "confluent.license: "---",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://p-og.prod:8081",
  "gcs.bucket.name": "kafka_load",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcs.format.avro.AvroFormat",
  "gcs.part.size": "5242880",
  "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
  "name": "gcs_sink_prod",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcs.storage.GcsStorage",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "auto.offset.reset": "latest"
}
```

Comment: I think that information is lost when its converted into a Connect Schema before the `format.class` is applied (because not all formats understand logicalType), but what happens when you add `value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support=true`?

Comment: good question. i'll add and see

Comment: hmm, nope still missing the logicalType property in the avro file

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the logicalType? In the past, I've only seen that on decimal types, and if using timestamps, consistent use of seconds/milliseconds/ISO8601 strings seems to be best

Comment: we're loading the data into BigQuery and timestamp columns have type long and cannot be used as timestamp in BigQuery. Changing the schema is a big hassle. Adding the logicalType: timestamp-millis will help to load the data in as timestamp in BigQuery.

Comment: Hmm. Other than the previous mentioned property, there's nothing that can really be changed about how the data is written/consumed. Writing to Parquet might be another option. Otherwise, you might be able to add some `transform` property to modify the timestamp fields into a format that works better for BQ

Comment: Also, there is a direct BigQuery sink, so you don't really need the GCS Sink. https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/index.html